# How to solve "ReferenceError", when loading script dynamically from external js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have home.php and ext.js file.

The procedure I want to make it, when I run home.php, I want to show dialog box.  When dialog box open, user can't access home.php before they click `button` from dialog box.

I make dialog box in ext.js file and call that dialog procedure from home.php like this,

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script> 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    create_dialog();
}); 
</script>
.....
```

In my ext.js file, I load jQuery and jQuery ui script dynamically.

```
//load jQuery
var q = document.createElement("script");
q.async = true;
q.src = "jquery-1.11.3.min.js";
var first = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
first.parentNode.insertBefore(q, first);

//load jQuery ui
var u= document.createElement("script");
u.async = true;
u.src = "jquery.ui/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js";
var first = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
first.parentNode.insertBefore(u, first);

function create_dialog() {
   $("<div>....</div>").dialog({
      autoOpen:true,
      width:'600px',
      modal: true,
      resizable:false,
      draggable:false,
      buttons:........
    });
}
```

All of above code is work before I clear the cache from browser history.

But if I clear cache and run home.php again, I get error in firebug like this,

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$("<div>....</div>").dialog({....
```

And sometimes I got above error and another error like this,

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    $("<div>....</div>").dialog({....

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
     factory( jQuery );
```

When I got this problem, the dialog box cannot show and user can access `home.php`. Its problem for me.

I already test with `loadScript(src,callback)` function but I got the same problem even I get callback success function. I don't know why?.

I very appreciate for any suggestion.

Comment: Check if it is including the jQuery libraries properly.

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` add jquery library file in your code before your external js `<script>` tag.

Comment: You have firstly to use `onload` event of jQuery script to load jQuery UI otherwise jQuery UI could be loaded before jQuery one (thta's the second message error). Then call `create_dialog()` method from jQuery UI script `onload` event. But it really looks like you are overcomplicating things here...